# @Before and @After annotations execution order for <include> and <exclude> tag in groups

Tags: testng, testng-annotation-test

In a testing.xml file, when executed with  and  tag, it has different behavior in execution @Before and @After annotations and kindly confirm if this is how it is designed.

I have a below BaseClass file with annotation defined for @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass, and with respect to groups = {"Windows","Android"} we have defined @BeforeGroups and @AfterGroups

```
public class BaseClass {
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("----@BeforeSuite function");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        System.out.println("----@AfterSuite function");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() { System.out.println("----------------@BeforeClass function"); }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() { System.out.println("----------------@AfterClass function"); }

    @BeforeGroups(alwaysRun = true, groups = {"Windows","Android"})
    public void beforeGroups() { System.out.println("----------------@BeforeGroups function"); }

    @AfterGroups(alwaysRun = true, groups = {"Windows","Android"})
    public void afterGroups() { System.out.println("----------------@AfterGroups function"); }
}
```

I have defined a PArameterSample class file which exteds the above BaseClass.

```
public class ParameterSample extends BaseClass {
    @Test(groups={"Windows"})
    public void simpleTest() {
        System.out.println("------------------------@Inside ParameterSample: simpleTest");
    }

    @Test(groups={"Android"})
    public void sample() {
        System.out.println("------------------------@Inside ParameterSample: sample");
    }

}
```

None of the annotation @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass has (alwaysRun = true) defined in the BaseClass file.

Below is the testng.xml which defines the groups tag to execute only "Windows" group with  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Regression1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Windows"></include>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="sample.ParameterSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

As we have not defined (alwaysRun=true) for @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass annotations, the o/p is inline as expected.

```
----------------@BeforeGroups function
------------------------@Inside ParameterSample: simpleTest
----------------@AfterGroups function
```

It executed only @BeforeGroups and @AfterGroups annotation and it has not executed any of the other annotations.

Now below XML has  tag instead of  tag which output is what I need clarification.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Regression1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="Windows"></exclude>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="sample.ParameterSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Below is the output of the XML.

```
----@BeforeSuite function
----------------@BeforeClass function
----------------@BeforeGroups function
------------------------@Inside ParameterSample: sample
----------------@AfterGroups function
----------------@AfterClass function
----@AfterSuite function
```

In the XML we have given  which is executing @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass annotations also even when (alwaysRun=true) is not defined.

Is the behavior correct for  tag, that it executes @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass class by default and only for  tag we need to define (alwaysRun=true) in other annotations if those annotations need to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior you described is correct. The `<run>` tag in TestNG executes all annotations in the class, even if they are not annotated with `alwaysRun=true`. The `<exclude>` tag excludes the specified groups from execution but does not exclude the annotations themselves.

In your example, the `<run>` tag in the first XML file includes the "Windows" group, so the `@BeforeGroups` and `@AfterGroups` annotations in the `BaseClass` are executed, even though they are not annotated with `alwaysRun=true`. The `<exclude>` tag in the second XML file excludes the "Windows" group, so the `@BeforeGroups` and `@AfterGroups` annotations are not executed, but the `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, `@BeforeSuite`, and `@AfterSuite` annotations are still executed because they are not excluded by the  tag.

To summarise:

`<run>` - All annotations in the class unless they are excluded by a `<exclude>` tag.

`<exclude>` - Annotations in the specified groups are not executed. Other annotations are still executed.